# RnR: rails_admin, polymorphic associations, and no klass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, rails-admin

OK I started with this question:
[RnR: Database normalization, rails models and associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673050/rnr-database-normalization-rails-models-and-associations)

I've set up the models as outlined.  I'm trying to use the [Rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) gem for the data maintenance. The issue is every polymorphic child table gives the following error:

```
    undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

However the parent record for location shows up, with fields for the associations in the list, but I cannot edit them.  I was thinking maybe seed data would help, but I'm not sure what the format for the object_type should be?  Is it case-sensitive, singular or plural?

Comment: Rails-admin and active-admin are both a real pain when trying to do stuff like this, are you sure your nested form is set up correctly?

Comment: Can you post the code for 2 of the models, controllers and the results of rake routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, was using the same name for the association between two different polymorphic associations...

Answer (score 0):

`object_type` is formatted exactly like the model name.

Let's assuming you have Comments which can belong to either Articles or Posts, and our polymorphic association is commentable (thus, `commentable_type` and `commentable_id`).

A comment for Article with id 1 would be

`commentable_type = 'Article'`

`commentable_id = 1`